# Contour integration, residues and precision of the poles

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, precision-and-accuracy

#### Task

I am trying to evaluate the contour integral of some functions. To have a concrete example, let's use
$$ f(z,s) = \frac{1+(4+2s)\, z}{z - \left( 9 + 35s + 24s^2 + 4s^3 \right) z^2 + 8z^3} $$

```
f[z_, s_] := (1 + (4 + 2*s)*z)/(z - (9 + 35*s + 24*s^2 + 4*s^3)*z^2 + 8*z^3)
```

and I want to evaluate

$$ \hat T(s) = \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}} \oint_{|z|=1} f(z,s)\, \mathrm dz $$

for $\Re(s) > 0$. My goal would be to find an analytic expression for the integral.

#### Method 1: NIntegrate

If I fix some value of $s$, say $s = 0.5 + 2\mathrm i$, I can of course evaluate the integral numerically:

```
NIntegrate[1/(2*π)*f[E^(I*ϕ), 0.5 + 2*I]*E^(I*ϕ), {ϕ, 0, 2*π}]
```

> 0.00415703 + 0.0498992 I

I guess that this is the correct result, so this is what I'll try to get with analytic methods.

#### Method 2: Integrate

Unfortunately, `Integrate` fails pretty hard:

```
Integrate[1/(2*π*I)*f[E^(I*ϕ), s]*I*E^(I*ϕ), {ϕ, 0, 2*π}]
```

> 1

#### Analyzing poles and residues

I know that my functions have poles at $z_0=0$ and at
$$ z_{1,2} = \frac{1}{16} \left( 9 + 35s + 24s^2 + 4s^3 \mp \sqrt{-32 + \left( 9 + 35s + 24s^2 + 4s^3 \right)^2} \right) . $$

```
sqrt = Sqrt[-32 + (9 + 35*s + 24*s^2 + 4*s^3)^2];
pole1[s_] := Evaluate[1/16*(9 + 35*s + 24*s^2 + 4*s^3 - sqrt)];
pole2[s_] := Evaluate[1/16*(9 + 35*s + 24*s^2 + 4*s^3 + sqrt)];
Simplify@f[pole1[s], s]
```

> ComplexInfinity

```
Simplify@f[pole2[s], s]
```

> ComplexInfinity

I can use `Residue` to calculate the residues at these poles:

```
Residue[f[z, s], {z, 0}]
```

> 1

```
N@pole1[0.5 + 2*I]
```

> -10.8696 + 11.5057 I

```
Residue[f[z, s], {z, pole1[s]}]
```

> (some lengthy expression...)

```
% /. s -> 0.5 + 2*I
```

> -0.00415703 - 0.0498992 I

```
N@pole2[0.5 + 2*I]
```

> -0.0054233 - 0.00574071 I

```
Residue[f[z, s], {z, pole2[s]}]
```

> (some lengthy expression...)

```
% /. s -> 0.5 + 2*I
```

> -0.995843 + 0.0498992 I

As you can see, `Integrate` only catches the pole at $z_0=0$. The pole $z_1$ is outside the contour, adding the residues at $z_0$ and $z_2$ gives the correct result.

#### Method 3: Residue Theorem

To evaluate the integral, we should of course sum all residues of the poles inside the contour.
In general, this will always be $z_0$ and one of $z_{1,2}$.
Due to the branch cut of the square root in the definition of `pole1` and `pole2`, these functions are however not continuous, and sometimes $z_1$ is the correct one to take and sometimes it is $z_2$.

Now, I first tried to define

```
hatT[s_] := Module[{pole},
  pole = If[Abs[pole1[s]] < Abs[pole2[s]], pole1[s], pole2[s]];
  Total[Residue[f[z, s], {z, #}] & /@ {0, pole}]]
```

This behaves in a rather strange way:

```
Chop@hatT[0.5 + 2*I]
  > 1.
```

gives the wrong result, while

```
N@hatT[1/2 + 2*I]
  > -0.0054233-0.00574071 I
```

is correct.

#### Fixed?

I figured out that the problem comes from the low precision of `0.5 + 2*I`.
The bad behavior can apparently be fixed by rationalizing the argument `s`:

```
hatT[s_] := Module[{pole, rs},
  rs = Rationalize[s, 0];
  pole = If[Abs[pole1[rs]] < Abs[pole2[rs]], pole1[rs], pole2[rs]];
  Total[Residue[f[z, rs], {z, #}] & /@ {0, pole}]]
```

#### Questions

Summarizing, my questions are:

- Why does `Integrate` fail to see one of the poles? Is there maybe even a simple fix for that?
- Is `Rationalize[s, 0]` the right thing to do? (It seems to work right now and I can also plot the function `hatT[s]`, but the first time I tried it with `Rationalize` somehow the plotting did not work, which I can't reproduce any more now.)
- Does someone have an idea on how to find an analytic expression for $\hat T(s)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a quite easy task for Integrate with a few transformations, if f rationalized. ( `Rationalize[s, 0]`is optimal.)

```
integrand = 1/(2*π)*f[E^(I*ϕ), 1/2 + 2*I]*E^(I*ϕ) // Simplify

NIntegrate[integrand, {ϕ, 0, 2*π}]

(*   0.00415703+ 0.0498992 I   *)

ce = integrand // ExpToTrig // 
        ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &;

{int = Integrate[ce, {ϕ, 0, 2*π}], int // N}

(*   {1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[83432339/85705131 - (5654752 I)/28568377], 
       0.00415703+ 0.0498992 I}   *)
```

Residue calculation

```
sol = Solve[(Denominator[f[z, s]] /. s -> 1/2 + 2*I) == 0, z]

(*   {{z -> 0}, {z -> 2/((-87 + 92 I) - Sqrt[-927 - 16008 I])}, {z -> 
       1/16 ((-87 + 92 I) - Sqrt[-927 - 16008 I])}}   *)

sol//N

(*   {{z -> 0.}, {z -> -0.0054233 - 0.00574071 I}, {z -> -10.8696 + 
11.5057 I}}   *)

{res =Residue[f[z, 1/2 + 2 I], {z, z /. sol[[1]]}] + 
     Residue[f[z, 1/2 + 2 I], {z, z /. sol[[2]]}] // FullSimplify,res//N}

(*   {1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[83432339/85705131 - (5654752 I)/28568377], 
      0.00415703+ 0.0498992 I}   *)
```

**Edit:  Appendix to Method 3: Residue Theorem**

Developing general operator.

```
sol = Solve[Denominator[f[z, s]] == 0, z];

pole1[s_] := Evaluate[z /. sol[[2]]]

pole2[s_] := Evaluate[z /. sol[[3]]]

hatT[s_] := (rs = Rationalize[s, 0];
           pole = 
   Which[Abs[pole1[rs]] < 1 && Abs[pole2[rs]] < 1, {pole1[rs], 
    pole2[rs]}, 
    Abs[pole1[rs]] < 1 && Abs[pole2[rs]] > 1, {pole1[rs]}, 
    Abs[pole1[rs]] > 1 && Abs[pole2[rs]] < 1, {pole2[rs]}];
    {tt = Total[Residue[f[z, rs], {z, #}] & /@ {0, Sequence @@ pole}], 
     N[tt]}) // FullSimplify
```

Compare with integration.

```
integrand[s_] := 1/(2*\[Pi])*f[E^(I*\[Phi]), s]*E^(I*\[Phi]) // Simplify

ce[s_] := integrand[s] // ExpToTrig // 
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &;

nint[s_] := NIntegrate[ce[s], {\[Phi], 0, 2*\[Pi]}]

int[s_] := {ii = 
            Integrate[ce[Rationalize[s, 0]], {\[Phi], 0, 2*\[Pi]}], ii // N}
```

Test

```
hatT[1/2 + 2 I]

(*   {1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[83432339/85705131 - (5654752 I)/28568377], 
      0.00415703+ 0.0498992 I}   *)
```

Comment: If $s=1/2 + 2\mathrm i$ is plugged in, the `// ExpToTrig // ComplexExpand` is not needed, Integrate already works fine. However, using `// ExpToTrig // ComplexExpand`, Integrate seems to give an expression for general `s` (even though it is in a weird ConditionalExpression), so thank you!

Comment: Why did you write the second part about residue calculation in your answer? That's the same thing I was doing already, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, of course it is the same in a slightly different form, together with analytic solutions. It shows, exact solution can be quite simple, not a lengthy expression.

Comment: So... sorry, but the places where I wrote "lengthy expression", I didn't plug s=1/2+2I in yet. Are you saying that you can get simple expressions that hold for general s?

Comment: I changed  the `hatT[s_] `a little bit and think, it workes. (Didn't regard the cases, where integration path is exactly on a singularity.)